# How can I use picker in Auto Rig?

Tags: auto-rig-pro

I installed Auto Rig 3.41.59 and I could bind the rig and everything works fine.

[image: Record_2021_03_22_14_05_39_313]

the only problem is I can't use the picker.

[image: Record_2021_03_22_14_06_57_237]

### [You can download the blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L49F2AgBxPm6f3ptbHjGW-t_186JcWyQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Shouldn't you be selecting in the left screen?

Comment: @Luciano No, in tutorials they used 2d picker to select easily

Comment: @Luciano as you can see in [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/5EotUuWASM4) when he selected 2d picker it will select the 3d bone automatically

Comment: I had the same problem:
The solution is to add addons (proxy_picker)[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eS78.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eS78.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

did you check if your proxy picker is the same version as the one in the the auto rig pro addon folder?  I updated the Mike rig to play with it, and used the proxy picker that come with the Mike rig and I had the same problem